# ImportError while importing test module in Docker

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv, pytest

When I run the following Pytest command in a virtual environment, it succeeds

`python3 -m pytest ./tests/unit/`

but if I go into the Docker container with bash and run it from /code, I get the following error:

```
_ ERROR collecting tests/unit/components/parser/s_parser/a/a_parser_test.py _
ImportError while importing test module '/code/tests/unit/components/parser/s_parser/a/a_parser_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.tests'; 'code' is not a package
___ ERROR collecting tests/unit/components/rrunner/runner/runner_test.py ____
ImportError while importing test module '/code/tests/unit/components/rrunner/runner/runner_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.tests'; 'code' is not a package
```

Docker command
`docker run --rm --network host -v $(pwd):/code container bash`

I see the **init**.py in Docker in the /code directory and every subdirectory.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.tests'; 'code'` is not a package
_ seem like issue in your code. not with docker

Comment: Are you mounting the package contents to `/code`? If yes, you can set `PYTHONPATH=/` to fix the import issue. However, the stdlib already has a module named `code` so I'd rename yours to avoid name shadowing.

Comment: @hoefling, that was the issue.  I changed the directory name to something else and that fixed it.